# MacBook Air heating up and lagging for no apparent reason

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, force-quit

Earlier today I had a few apps open, and one of them was Safari, which had some tabs open which may have been using a lot of energy and/or memory.

(One of them was this program by me which draws a grid of squares in isometric 3D, but unfortunately creates and stores a new object literal in the memory every time the function gets called to map a point from 3D onto 2D. This function gets called about 1600 times each frame, about 60 frames per second. Not a big problem unless I left it open for a while, which I did.)

So then I got the spinning wheel of death on some apps, various Safari tabs weren't even rendering, and my computer fan was whirring/purring faintly. That's all well and good, because I force quit everything, and when that didn't help completely, held the power button and shut down my computer, only to find that when I powered back on my computer it still was hot and stuff.

I guess my question is, does leaving your computer screen and applications on for a long time make it complain and it will still be laggy and hot and stuff even after you terminate all processes? Or is my computer just **getting old** so I *have* to buy a new one in which case tsk tsk Apple. I have a Early 2014, 13" MacBook Air.

Comment: You if keep observing this behavior with no apparent reason, you should consider getting it inspected by an authorized technician or service provider.

Comment: Ok. I think the lagging has sufficed. Thanks fir the advice.